# Is it possible to have a non-conservative vector field, such that the closed loop integral is $0$ for only some specific path(s)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, vector-fields, conservative-field

I was wondering whether there exists some non-conservative field in which the closed loop integral over some specific path(s) is $0$, even if it's not $0$ for all the closed loop integrals. Or to put it in another way, is it true that any closed loop integral in a non conservative field is always non zero. 
I'd be much obliged if someone could give me an example of such a field, or at least give me some pointers.

Comment: Are you ruling out a small conservative field region embedded in a larger non-conservative field?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. But that would mean defining the vector field piecewise. I wondered if there's something that satisfies the criterion without being defined piecewise.

Comment: what do you mean by (not) "defined piecewise"? I think you mean that your vector field should  be globally defined in term of *elementary functions*. Well, this is problematic because elementary functions are *real analytic* and the curl of the field would be consequently a real analytic function (I am referring to its components). A real analytic function vanishing in a neighborhood vanishes everywhere in its domain (supposed to be open and connected). So if a field "constructed out elementary functions" is irrotational somewhere it is irrotational everywhere.

Comment: In other words close loops with non-vanishing integral can arise only because they bound some singularity of the field. Locally, an irrotational field is always conservative. Therfore, from your viewpoint the situation pictured in the answer by BMS is essentially the only possible, barring obvious changes and generalizations.

Comment: Related: [If the work done by a force along a closed path is zero, is it necessarily conservative?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515326/238167)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How picky are you about singularities?

Consider the magnetic field of a steady current oriented in the $+z$ direction. The field is

$$\vec B \sim \frac{1}{r}\hat \phi,$$

If you do a naive calculation of the curl, you'll find it's zero. And indeed, if you evaluate a closed line integral that does **not** bound $(x,y)=(0,0)$, you'll get zero. (Think of Ampere's law; no current enclosed) But this *mistake* in calculating the curl comes about from not correctly considering the $\delta$-function current source.

If your path **does** bound $(x,y)=(0,0)$, you'll get something that's non-zero for the closed line integral.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd be much obliged if someone could give me an example of such a
>   field

Consider a vector field $\vec F$ with non-zero curl in the $z$ direction only:

$$\nabla \times \vec F = \left(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} -  \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right)\hat z $$

An example of such a field is

$$\vec F = -y \hat x + x \hat y$$

which has curl

$$\nabla \times \vec F = 2\hat z$$

so $\vec F$ is non-conservative.  By Stoke's theorem, for a closed contour in the $z=z_0$ plane enclosing an area $A$, the line integral along that contour will have the value of $2A$.

Clearly, for plane areas parallel to the $z$ axis, there is zero flux of $\nabla \times \vec F$ through, thus, the closed contour integral of $\vec F$ in such a plane will be zero by Stoke's theorem.

To verify, pick a contour within the plane defined by, e.g., $y = 1$.

Integrate the field along the path from $(0,1,0)$ to $(1,1,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$ to $(0,1,1)$ to $(0,1,0)$

There is no component of $\vec F$ in the $z$ direction so the only contributions are the integrals along the $x$ direction.

$$\int_0^1 (-1)\hat x \cdot \hat x dx + \int_1^0 (-1)\hat x \cdot \hat x dx = -1 + 1 = 0$$

So, this is a simple example of a non-conservative vector field and a closed contour integral in that field that is zero.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is trivially positive. Take a conservative vector field $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and consider a closed smooth curve $\gamma$ in a open bounded region, say $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$. Obviously $\int_\gamma X \cdot d x =0$. Next consider another vector field $Y$ in $\mathbb R^n$ which is non-conservative  in a similar region $\Omega'$ **disconnected**  from $\Omega$. $\Omega'$ must contain a curve $\gamma'$ such that $\int_{\gamma'} Y\cdot d x \neq 0$, othervise $Y$ would be conservative therein.

Finally consider a couple of smooth real valued functions $f$ and $g$ with
$f(x)=1$ in $\Omega$ and $f(x)=0$ in $\Omega'$,  and $g(x)=1$ in $\Omega'$ and $g(x)=0$ in $\Omega$ and $f(x)+g(x)=1$ everywhere (it is a trivial partition of unity, which always exists)-
The vector field $Z = fX + gY$ is smooth on the whole space $\mathbb R^n$ and it is not conservative because
$$\int_{\gamma'} Z \cdot d x  = \int_{\gamma'} Y \cdot d x \neq 0$$
however it verifies
$$\int_{\gamma} Z \cdot d x  = \int_{\gamma} X \cdot d x = 0\:.$$